# Why it's not safe to do DOM transformation in Pre-linking function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

In `$compile` there is a `Pre-linking-function` and in the `AngularJS` API Documentation they are write that it's not safe to do DOM transformation in the `Pre-linking-function`. Does anyone knows why?

[Reference to section of API Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#pre-linking-function)

Comment: `Executed before the child elements are linked. Not safe to do DOM transformation since the compiler linking function will fail to locate the correct elements for linking.` - that mean the element is not present yet...

Answer (score 2):

## First, what is linking?

`linking` is the process that angular uses to bind the model to the DOM.

> The link function is responsible for registering DOM listeners as well as updating the DOM. It is executed after the template has been cloned. This is where most of the directive logic will be put. *~AngularJS API Documentation*

#### Below is a really great diagram to show how Angular works

[image]

## So why you can't manipulate the `DOM` in `pre-linking`?

Because `pre-linking` occurs before the linking happens (again this is the part where angular compiles and binds the model to the `DOM` so it can manipulate it).  So during `pre-linking` angular is not aware of the `DOM` and its elements to be able to manipulate it at all.

#### To Reference the Diagram:

- `pre-linking` would be **before** all of the arrows/lines are drawn between the boxes
- `linking` would be the phase **during** the arrows/lines being drawn
- `post-linking` would be **after** all of the arrows/lines are drawn and the pieces are connected

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that, but this doesn't explains why i should not manipulate the template DOM of my directive.

Comment: @Christoph in relation to your question, you can't manipulate the template during the `pre-link`, however; you can during `link` or `post-link`

Answer (score 2):

The main practical difference between `pre` and `post` linking functions lies in the fact that pre-linking functions are executed from parent directives to children directives, and post-linking functions are executed in the opposite order.

This is the result of `$compile` service behaviour which is explained [in the manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#pre-linking-function):

> Pre-linking function
>
> Executed before the child elements are linked. Not safe to do DOM
>   transformation since the compiler linking function will fail to locate
>   the correct elements for linking.
>
> Post-linking function
>
> Executed after the child elements are linked.

In general this behaviour affects any situation where pre-linking function expects something from one of its children but will not get it because pre/post-linking functions in children (which run after parent's pre-link) didn't take that into account and messed up each other's controllers or DOM somehow. But the manual implies the very specific situation.

In [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PGTVVCtRDPaEJb8xsBah?p=preview)

```
app.directive('abba', function () {
  return {
    template: '<a><b></b></a>',
    link: {
      pre: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        console.log('hi from this world')
        element.find('a').remove()
      }
    }
  }
});

app.directive('a', function () {
  return {
    link: {
      pre: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        console.log('hi from that world')
      }
    }    
  };
});

app.directive('b', function () {
  return {
    link: {
      pre: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
       console.log('no hi from that world') 
      }
    }   
  };
});
```

this will result in

> hi from this world
>
> hi from that world
>
> Error: linkNode is undefined
>   nodeLinkFn@https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js:8330:9

Obviously, `a` directive is a living dead here, its pre-link is still alive. `$compile` also expects to link its children but failed to find the parent.

This won't happen [if post-links are used instead](http://plnkr.co/edit/RIqiWF8czb46wgpOsiTK?p=preview):

> yes hi from that world
>
> hi from that world
>
> hi from this world

so `a` and `b` can die peacefully after they served their purposes.